# which tool is required to develop web application using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs. Are there any good tools available which will assist me in coding angularjs apps? I am looking for a tool which will provide auto suggestions, syntax error highlighters etc for javascript.

Comment: Brackets - with some adapted plugins like jshint or AngularJS-brackets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrain Webstorm 8 with angularjs integtarion is the best fit

I recommend follow the article [angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web is nice